# How to add onClickListener for the hardware back button in Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, back-button

I'm trying to set a onClickListener for the hardware back button in Fragment. Since I'm in a fragment I'm unable to use onBackButtonPressed(). Can someone please tell me what I can do in this case.

Comment: `Since I'm in a fragment I'm unable to use onBackButtonPressed().` **NO**. Override `onBackButtonPressed()` in the Activity which contains the Fragment, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've almost achieved my task, but with a small problem. The problem is that now when I pressed the back button the full screen exits and comes back to the normal screen. But after two seconds from that the entire application gets closed. Can you please suggest me some ideas why it is happening like that.

Comment: When you press the back button you go to the previous Activity in the BackStack (or exits your app, if that was the last Activity). So, in the `onBackPressed()` method, if you only have a single Activity, you have to perform some checks: where was I coming from? which was the last active Fragment? should I open some other Fragment? ...

Comment: hi.. Thanks for the answer, but this same problem doesn't happens in a portrait view. It happens only in the landscape view.

Comment: No, it's the same in both orientation modes. Only that - when you rotate your device - the app is **restarted**, so you start from the main Activity again (and pressig back will close the app). As I said, try to override `onBackButtonPressed()` in the Activity and set some variable to know where you are (i.e.: mainActivity = true). So you can act accordingly in the back button pressure (i.e.: display a confirmation dialog "Do you really want to quit?") and eventually cancel the closing action.